# Is this induction question wrong or am I going insane?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Here's a question that I've come across: Prove by induction that for every integer $n$ greater than or equal to $1$,

$${\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}} \frac{1}{i} \ge 1 +\frac{n}{2}.$$

Now I know how to prove by induction, but wouldn't this fail $p(1)$ since

$$\frac{1}{1} \ge 1 +\frac{1}{2}$$ is not true?

Comment: Note that $2^1=2$.

Comment: The case $n=1$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^2\frac1i=\frac11+\frac12\ge\cdots$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the upper bound of the summation;

If $n = 1$, then we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^2 \frac1i = 1 + \frac12 \geq 1 + \frac12$$

which is definitely true.

Given the discussion in the comments, I expand my answer to include the induction proof as I would do it:

**(PROOF BY INDUCTION:)**

We already have the base case for $n = 1$; Assume it is true up to $k$. We show it is true for $k + 1$.

The summation becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1i = \sum_{i=1}^{2^k} \frac1i + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1i \geq 1 + \frac{k}{2} + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1i$$

which holds because of the induction step. We want to check if

$$1 + \frac{k}{2} + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1k \geq 1 + \frac{k+1}{2} = 1 + \frac{k}{2} + \frac12$$

it suffices to show that

$$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1i \geq \frac12$$

which is, indeed, true. Notice that every term on that series is greater than, or equal to, $\frac1{2^{k+1}}$:

$$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1i \geq \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1{2^{k+1}} = 2^k\cdot \frac1{2^{k+1}} = \frac12$$

which concludes the proof.

Comment: Now I'm curious how this is going to end.  During the induction step, does the following reasoning hold:  ${\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2^{n+1}}} \frac{1}{i} \ge 1 +\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\geq 1+\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: I don't think you wrote the inequality you want to prove! check that ;)

Comment: I got ya, there should be an $n+1$ in that middle piece.

Comment: @emka indeed; did you manage to finish it?

Comment: I'm wondering if you did as well

Comment: @ShawnJavadi check my edited answer now ;)

Comment: If a sentence ends in mathmode and an exclamation mark, I will always read it as 'factorial'. Good thing $k+1! = k+1$ or I would've been confused ;)

Comment: @Therkel indeed :b thanks for the tip

Answer (score 8):

Neither: the question is not wrong and you are also not going insane ... You just made a little mistake. :)

Comment: It was a binary question; are you sure we should disregard the Law of the Excluded Middle?  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard Well, either we disregard it or we don't. :)